# How to make dual y axis bar plots (dodge) in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, multiple-columns

I am trying to make dual bar plot in single X axis, how to perform it? I know how to do with line plot. for example I am using `mtcars` data. Also i want to add legends and error line in that bars.

```
library(ggplot2)

scaleFactor <- max(mtcars$cyl) / max(mtcars$hp)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=disp)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(y=cyl), method="loess", col="blue") +
  geom_smooth(aes(y=hp * scaleFactor), method="loess", col="red") +
  scale_y_continuous(name="cyl", sec.axis=sec_axis(~./scaleFactor, name="hp")) +
  theme(
    axis.title.y.left=element_text(color="blue"),
    axis.text.y.left=element_text(color="blue"),
    axis.title.y.right=element_text(color="red"),
    axis.text.y.right=element_text(color="red")
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

the data would need to be restructured, in order to function properly with ggplot.

Here is how I did it with the example of three columns and rows of mtcars:

```
# Only use first 3 rows and columns
mtcarsmod <- mtcars[1:3, 1:3]

# Restructure data
Car <- rownames(mtcarsmod)
Part <- colnames(mtcarsmod)
Value <- as.vector(t(mtcarsmod))
mtcarsmod <- data.frame("Car"=rep(Car,each=length(Part)), "Part"=rep(Part, times=length(Car)), "Value"= Value)


# Visualize data
library(ggplot2)

# Have Cars on X axis
plot <- ggplot(mtcarsmod, aes(x=Car, y=Value, fill=Part)) +   
               geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")
plot

# Have Variables on X axis
plot <- ggplot(mtcarsmod, aes(x=Part, y=Value, fill=Car)) +   
               geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")
plot


# Have Cars on Y axis
plot <- ggplot(mtcarsmod, aes(x=Value, y=Car, fill=Part)) +   
              geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")
plot

# Have Variables on Y axis
plot <- ggplot(mtcarsmod, aes(x=Value, y=Part, fill=Car)) +   
              geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")
plot
```